# How to write combined query from azure table storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am trying to query from a table so that the name and partition key (combined) unique.
I am doing this right now:

```
public Spec(string name)
{
    Query = new TableQuery<TableEntity>()
        .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(nameof(table.Name), QueryComparisons.Equal, name));
}
```

but I also need to check partition key exists withing this name. So need to query the table along with the partition key and the name.
Can anybody help with this? How to query these as combined query.

Comment: Table-queries are only concerned with the contents of entities' properties (columns) within a table. A table's name is completely irrelevant.

Comment: This doesn't look like real code to me - you should not have a table-type named `Table`. And what is `table.Name`? Where is it coming from? (It isn't a parameter of your method). And `public Spec(string name)` looks like a constructor - but you should not be performing IO or much heavy-lifting in a constructor (in fact, you _cannot_ do async IO in a ctor anyway).

Comment: Spec is the method I use to pass the name on it. and yes, Table is the entity class. I use Table here just for showcasing.

Comment: `public Spec(string name)` is not a method, that's a constructor. It's missing its return-type. And you haven't answered my question where I ask where `table.Name` is coming from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like below:

```
public Spec(string name)
{
    var filterCondition1 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "PartitionKeyValue");
    var filterCondition2 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(nameof(table.Name), QueryComparisons.Equal, name);
    Query = new TableQuery<TableEntity>()
        .Where(TableQuery.CombineFilters(filterCondition1, "AND", filterCondition2));
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank for the suggestions. Do you know if we can check from this Query result if either one of is unique.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you please explain?

Comment: Okay, why I am doing this is that: I am trying to validate for the unique name. So, there are multiple names are stored under the same Partition Key.  For example:
PartitionKey:1, RowKey:1, Name: 'First Name'
PartitionKey:1, RowKey: 2, Name:'First Name'

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to find out if `Name = 'First Name'` is unique in a partition. Correct?

Comment: Yes, This is what I am trying to find.

Comment: It's actually simple. You simply execute the query and count the number of entities returned :).

Comment: Could you give me an example with this? This is for the first time I am doing something with this

Comment: What's the SDK you're using?

Comment: I think it is .net core 3.1